# CakePhp Fatal Error

Tags: cakephp

Please Give me a solutuion
Fatal error: Call to a member function writeBuffer() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\views\layouts\default.ctp on line 17

Comment: I'd figure you were trolling but let's give you the benefit of the doubt:
Step one: Read the FAQ. Also, read the big things that pop up when you go to ask a question rather than skipping them and posting the question anyways. That is how your question will be answered.

Oh, and we can't see your D:\ drive.. or line 17. Nor do you give even a vague introduction to what you are asking.

Comment: Can you explain it more? What are you doing? What is your code? Right now, nobody can help you if don't know what are you doing.

Comment: Do you think it would help if you'd show at least what you have on line 17 in default.ctp?

Answer (score 11):

Check that in your controller you have the following line after the class declaration:

```
public $helpers = array('Js');
```

Or to make the code in the layout a little more resilient edit `views\layouts\default.ctp` and use the following to write the contents of the JsHelper buffer:

```
<?php
if (class_exists('JsHelper') && method_exists($this->Js, 'writeBuffer')) echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

Comment: This may not be a real question but at least someone bothered to answer it - and gave me my answer. Thanks.